# Angular2 Databinding across application instances-how to stop?

Tags: angular

My Angular2 (RC1) textbox databinding works fine. But if i open up **a 2nd instance** of my app (either on a tab on the same browser, or, a completely different browser), the databound textbox seems to be linked together.

This means when I **change my textbox on one instance** of my app, the **change shows across all the other instances**.

How can i stop this so that each time I launch my application, it is treated as a unique instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a browserSync behavior, you can disable it by creating a `bs-config.js` file in your project root directory "next to package.json"

```
module.exports = { 
        ghostMode: {
            clicks: true,
            forms: true,
            scroll: false
        },  

        // Or switch them all off in one go
        ghostMode: false
};
```

The configuration taken from [browserSync configurations](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/)

Comment: Thank-you, that was exactly what I was after (oh so much to learn with our new Angular lol!)